# Code coverage issues after migrating from VS2010 to VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, code-coverage

Recently I migrated all my C# projects from VS2010 to VS2013. There were barely any code changes required but immediately after I checked in the projects, I noticed that CI started failing. On checking the issue, I realized that the coverage file generated after running unit tests was not being generated in the location specified in the `.testsettings` file. In the Test Results Names section of Test Settings in VS2010, I configured a user defined naming scheme and unchecked the Append date-time stamp checkbox. This would generate the coverage file in \\data.coverage. After migrating to VS2013, the coverage file is getting generated in a Test Settings folder which believe is the default location when the Default naming scheme is chosen.

On researching a bit, I found an [MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx) and a few other blogs posts suggesting doing away with the `.testsettings` file and adopting the new `.runsettings` file. The weird thing is Microsoft is recommending usage of the .runsettings file but don't seem to deliver a default one which I can build upon. In any case, I did create one based on the sample provided on the same MSDN post. It did work for me as far as creation of the coverage file is concerned but I again faced the same problem that it is getting generated in a Test Results folder. The bigger problem is that a sub-folder with some GUID type name is created into which the coverage file is dumped and it changes every time a test is run with code coverage ON.

I wonder if there's a way make my VS2010 settings work as expected in VS2013 or using the `.runsettings` file, can I provide the complete path where the coverage file should be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Test->Test Settings->Select Test Settings File and select the .testsettings file associated with your test project. It's a hack but always works.

Comment: I realized it a long time back. Anyway, accepting the answer just in case someone else having a similar issue stumbles upon this post.